# Javascript - how to add header in CallPrint function

Tags: javascript, php, forms, printing

I have javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function CallPrint(strid) {  
    var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);  
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0, top=0, width=970, height=500, toolbar=0, scrollbars=0, status=0');  
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);  
    WinPrint.document.close();  
    WinPrint.focus();  
    WinPrint.print();  
    WinPrint.close();  
    }  
</script>
```

and in the button:

```
onClick="javascript:CallPrint('printarea')"
```

Now is working and I can print certain part of the page, but I want to add header with logo and some contact information which show only when print the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@media print` CSS tag. Essentially create a style which has `display:none` and in `@media print` make it visible.

Something like:

```
<style media="screen">
  .onlyPrint{ display: none; }
</style>

<style media="print">
  .onlyPrint{ display: block; }
</style>
```

You call your javascript as regular and depending on whether the rendition is on the screen or the printer, the CSS will handle the show/hide of the header with logo

Comment: I can't make it work. Add new style media="print" in the page with my css code but don't work. 
<style media="print">
#printarea { background:#999; font-size:36px; }
.print { display: block; background:#999; font-size:36px; }
</style>

Comment: This is a good starting point: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: OMG I try everything include article from the link and others articles and don't work.

Comment: Finaly just put the code in: @media screen { .noprint { display: none; } } and everything is working. Thanks a lot raidenace :)

Comment: There is no greater satisfaction, than when nothing seems to work and suddenly everything comes together, right? :)